# SP2013: SPDuplicateObjectException on SPDIagnosticsServiceBase.GetLocal

Tags: c#, exception, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I have made a custom Diagnostic service on my SharePoint 2013 farm extending the SPDiagnosticsServiceBase class.

```
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace Custom.Sharepoint.Services.Logging
{
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Guid("DBEEB5AB-C5A7-46B5-A2BB-5581F960C333")]
    public class CustomLoggingService : SPDiagnosticsServiceBase
    {
        public static string CustomLoggingServiceName = "Custom Logging Service";
        public static string CustomLoggingServiceTypeName = "Custom Logs";

        public enum CategoryId
        {
            General = 0,
            Base = 100,
            QA = 200,
            Admin = 300
        }

        public CustomLoggingService()
        {

        }

        public CustomLoggingService(string name, SPFarm farm) : base(CustomLoggingServiceName, farm)
        {

        }

        public static CustomLoggingService Local
        {
            get
            {
                return GetLocal<CustomLoggingService>();
            }
        }

        public override string DisplayName
        {
            get
            {
                return CustomLoggingServiceName;
            }
        }

        public override string TypeName
        {
            get
            {
                return CustomLoggingServiceTypeName;
            }
        }

        protected override IEnumerable<SPDiagnosticsArea> ProvideAreas()
        {
            List<SPDiagnosticsCategory> categories = new List<SPDiagnosticsCategory>();
            foreach (string catName in Enum.GetNames(typeof(CategoryId)))
            {
                uint catId = (uint)(int)Enum.Parse(typeof(CategoryId), catName);
                categories.Add(new SPDiagnosticsCategory(catName, TraceSeverity.Verbose, EventSeverity.Error, 0, catId));
            }

            yield return new SPDiagnosticsArea(CustomLoggingServiceName, categories);
        }
        public SPDiagnosticsCategory this[CategoryId id]
        {
            get
            {
                return Areas[CustomLoggingServiceName].Categories[id.ToString()];
            }
        }

        public static void LogError(CategoryId category, string errorMessage, TraceSeverity severity)
        {
            SPDiagnosticsCategory cat = Local.Areas[CustomLoggingServiceName].Categories[category.ToString()];
            Local.WriteTrace(0, cat, severity, errorMessage);
        }
    }
}
```

When Local is used in the LogError method the [GetLocal](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee547900.aspx) method throws the following exception:

> Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPDuplicateObjectException: An object of the type Custom.Sharepoint.Services.Logging.CustomLoggingService named "Custom Logging Service" already exists under the parent Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPFarm named "SharePoint_Config_825b764b-31e1-4f9e-a722-558c56a5b0af".  Rename your object or delete the existing object.
>   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPConfigurationDatabase.StoreObject(SPPersistedObject obj, Boolean storeClassIfNecessary, Boolean ensure)
>   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPConfigurationDatabase.Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.ISPPersistedStoreProvider.PutObject(SPPersistedObject persistedObject, Boolean ensure)
>   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPPersistedObject.BaseUpdate()
>   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPDiagnosticsServiceBase.Update()
>   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPDiagnosticsServiceBase.GetLocalToFarm[T](SPFarm farm)
>   at Custom.Sharepoint.Services.Logging.CustomLoggingService.get_Local()
>   at Custom.Sharepoint.Services.Logging.CustomLoggingService.LogError(CategoryId category, String errorMessage, TraceSeverity severity)
>   at Custom.Sharepoint.QA.Features.QAProbe.QAProbeEventReceiver.logToULS(String message, TraceSeverity severity)
>   at Custom.Sharepoint.QA.Features.QAProbe.QAProbeEventReceiver.FeatureActivated(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties)
>   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFeature.DoActivationCallout(Boolean fActivate, Boolean fForce)
>   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFeature.Activate(SPSite siteParent, SPWeb webParent, SPFeaturePropertyCollection props, SPFeatureActivateFlags activateFlags, Boolean fForce)

The tricky part here is that I get this exception only when LogError is called from a FeatureActivated event or a Timer Job. If it's called from a webpart, I don't have any issues. And this only occurs since a certain time. I did install the latest SP update and ran a PSConfigUI on the farm. I can't say this is the exact cause. In addition to this, I only experience the issue on my Dev environment but now I don't want to deploy any updates to my solution on prod and break everything.

The Exception shows that the GetLocal method calls the [GetLocalToFarm](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee544229.aspx) method but I tried to use it directly and I get the same result.

I tought that the GetLocal would actually get the handle on the existing object but according to the exception it looks like it's trying to create it and since it already exists it throws the exception... I need to use the local object since I want to use the Logging service in place so our admins can manage in CA the logs levels being captured. (My custom logs service does appear in the diagnostic logging configuration of the CA)

I use this piece of code to log error messages from any parts of my other custom made solutions:

```
CustomLoggingService.LogError(CustomLoggingService.CategoryId.QA, "Message from the QA Solution in the ULS", TraceSeverity.High);
```

Thanks